# Ambiguous type of "triangle" operator for sum types

Tags: type-theory, functional-programming, category-theory, haskell

In  Meijer, Fokkinga and Patersons "Functional Programming with Bananas, Lenses, Envelopes and Barbed Wire" the ∇ operator for sum types is introduced which removes the tags from its argument:

∇ _|_ = _|_

∇ (i, x) = x

What is the type of this operator? Something like

A|B -> A U B

?

As the article is recommended on the Haskell wiki, how could this operator be implemented in haskell?

Comment: should be something similar to the [`:+:`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html#t::-43-:)

Comment: @Apoorv but :+: acts on types